# Redireccionar PORT con determinada URL en HTACCESS

Tags: nodejs, .htaccess, nginx

Estoy tratando de hacer un deploy en un hosting compartido el cual tiene NGINX como servidor de estaticos.
El caso es que necesito poner una app de node para manejar el correo via smtp (con nodemailer)
No quiero servir los estaticos desde node sino desde nginx.
Al ser un hosting compartido no tengo acceso a la configuracion de nginx y lo tengo que hacer a traves de .htaccess.
Este es el codigo inicial.

```
#cPanel_HTTPS_INICIO
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
#cPanel_HTTPS_FIN
```

Pero para utilizar node tengo que cambiar el proxy a esto:

```
#cPanel_HTTPS_INICIO
DirectoryIndex ""
 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/index.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:3000/ [P,L]
 
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:3000/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:3000/$1 [P,L]
#cPanel_HTTPS_FIN
```

y aqui es cuando ya no puedo servir los estaticos con nginx.
Como podria escribir una regla para que por ej si la url es https:[www.misite.com/mail](http://www.misite.com/mail) me redireccione al port 3000 y si es cualquier otra siga con nginx

edit:
Encontre por ahi este codigo que intuyo debe estar cerca de lo que necesito pero de seguro debe haber algo mal escrito (hoy es la primera vez que me topo con htaccess)

```
#cPanel_HTTPS_INICIO
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^3000$
RewriteRule ^sendmail/(.*[^/])/?$ http://127.0.0.1:3000/sendmail/$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
#cPanel_HTTPS_FIN
```